# my date function is giving different values?

Tags: php, datetime

```
   class Feedback extends Connection
{

    private $feed_name;
    private $feed_email;
    private $feed_msg;
    private $date_sent;


    public function setfeed_name($nam='')
    {
        $this->feed_name=$nam;
    }
    public function setfeed_email($mail='')
    {
        $this->feed_email=$mail;
    }
    public function setfeed_msg($msg='')
    {
        $this->feed_msg=$msg;
    }
    public function setdate_feed()
    {
        $this->date_sent=date('y-m-d h:i:s');
    }



public function insertfeed()

{
    //echo $this->date_sent;
    $this->sql="INSERT INTO feedback_tbl (id,name,email,msg,date_sent) VALUES ('','$this->feed_name','$this->feed_email','$this->feed_msg','$this->date_sent')";
    $this->res=mysqli_query($this->conxn,$this->sql) or die($this->error=mysqli_error($this->conxn));
    //$this->affRows=mysqli_affected_rows($this->res);
    //if($this->affRows>0)
    //{
        return true;
        //echo $this->date_sent;

}

}

echo $this->date_sent;
```

**process.php**

```
<?php
require_once('../classes/db-connection.class.php');
require_once('../classes/feedback.class.php');
require_once('../classes/locate.class.php');



//creating an object
$objFeedback=new Feedback();

//setting the parameters
$name=mysqli_real_escape_string($objFeedback->conxn,$_POST['feed_name']);
$email=mysqli_real_escape_string($objFeedback->conxn,$_POST['feed_email']);
$message=mysqli_real_escape_string($objFeedback->conxn,$_POST['feed_msg']);
//setting objects variables
$objFeedback->setfeed_name($name);
$objFeedback->setfeed_email($email);
$objFeedback->setfeed_msg($message);
$objFeedback->setdate_feed();

$flag=$objFeedback->insertfeed();
if($flag==true)
{
    new Locate('../../../index.php?success='.base64_encode('Feedback succesfully delivered.'));

}
else
{
    new Locate('../../../index.php?error='.base64_encode('Feedback is not delivered.'));
}

?>
```

**Gives `2015-09-13 05:19:34` This is wrong answer**

But when I replace this `date()` function inside sql statement it provides correct answer.

```
$this->sql="INSERT INTO feedback_tbl (id,name,email,msg,date_sent) VALUES ('','$this->feed_name','$this->feed_email','$this->feed_msg',date('y-m-d h:i:s')";
```

**Gives `2015-09-13 11:59:12` This is correct answer**

Why i am getting this diffeerent value please help me?

Comment: Well, it turns out, we need to see a full code, because the first code makes little sense

Comment: I have edited my code ..!! please give me the reason.

Comment: What is the type of date_sent field?

Comment: When and where you ran the ->setdate_feed() method?

Comment: date_sent field is DATETIME type

Comment: In process.php     $objFeedback->setdate_feed();

Comment: After form submit? Please copy your process.php too

Comment: i edited with process.php

Comment: in insertfeed() method, after $this->sql line put this: echo $this->sql; exit; Here the date is ok?

Comment: what to do to get true value??

Comment: Just echo $this->sql before $this->res=mysqli_query... What is the result?

Comment: INSERT INTO feedback_tbl (id,name,email,msg,date_sent,ip_address,country) VALUES ('','manam','mna@mzn.om','this is a test','15-09-14 02:54:20','::1','')..               The given value of time is wrong but date is correct.